# Choose the correct separator with boto library

Tags: python, amazon-s3, path, boto

In python a good way to generate path depending on operating system is:

`import os
os.path.join('folder', 'subfolder', 'filename')`

But when using boto library for s3 protocol, I should use the specific separator for s3 service and not this from my host operating system. Is there something like boto.path.join in this library ?